# How do I formulate a conditional function

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, plot, conditional-statements

I am trying to formulate te the following functions in python and I want to plot them

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ss = np.linspace(300, 1000, 15)

def PT3000(ss):
    if ss < 318.842719019854:
        PT3 = 4.602 + 37440.0/ss
    else :
        PT3 =-0.3 + 3600.0/ss
    return PT3

def PT2000(ss):
    if ss < 318.842719019854:
        PT2 = 4.602 + 37440.0/ss
    elif ss > 945.33959:
        PT2 =-0.3 + 3600.0/ss
    else:
        PT2 = 6.87109574235995e-6*ss**0.5*(-1 + 96000.0/ss) + 62.144
    return PT2

fig= plt.figure()
plt.plot(ss,PT2000(ss))
plt.plot(ss,PT3000(ss))
plt.title('Productietijd [24x12]')
plt.xlabel('Verstijverafstand [mm]')
plt.ylabel('Productijd van een paneel [uur]')
plt.grid(visible=True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I run into an error but I don't understand what to do with it

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: For numpy arrays, you need `np.where` instead of `if`.  `PT3 = np.where(ss < 318.842719019854, 4.602 + 37440.0/ss, -0.3 + 3600.0/ss)`.  You'll need a nested `np.where` when there are more ifs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply `PT2000` and `PT3000` to *each element* of `ss`. However, Python passes the entire array `ss` at once and lets NumPy handle it.

[Comparison of NumPy arrays returns an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous), so code like `ss < 318.842719019854` results in an array of Boolean values. Thus, the `if` statement becomes something like this:

```
if np.array([False, True, False, ...]):
    # do stuff
    ...
```

"The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous", because the array can contain both `True` values and `False` values.

The solution that's usually suggested is to "use a.any() or a.all()", which check whether *any* or *all* elements of the array are `True`. This is not what you need here, since piecewise functions like `PT2000` and `PT3000` act on individual numbers, not entire arrays.

You can use [`numpy.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to apply your functions elementwise:

```
PT3000_vectorized = np.vectorize(PT3000)
plt.plot(ss, PT2000_vectorized(ss))
```

This will iterate over `ss` and pass its *individual elements* to the function, so comparisons will simply involve `float`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.legend as legend
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ss = np.linspace(300, 1000, 15)

def PT3000(ss):
    if np.all(ss < 318.842719019854):
        PT3 = 4.602 + 37440.0/ss
    else :
        PT3 =-0.3 + 3600.0/ss
    return PT3

def PT2000(ss):
    if np.all(ss < 318.842719019854) :
        PT2 = 4.602 + 37440.0/ss
    elif np.all(ss > 945.33959):
        PT2 =-0.3 + 3600.0/ss
    else:
        PT2 = 6.87109574235995e-6*ss**0.5*(-1 + 96000.0/ss) + 62.144
    return PT2

fig= plt.figure()
plt.plot(ss,PT2000(ss), label='PT2000')
plt.plot(ss,PT3000(ss), label='PT3000')
plt.title('Productietijd [24x12]')
plt.xlabel('Verstijverafstand [mm]')
plt.ylabel('Productijd van een paneel [uur]')
plt.grid(visible=True)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```